# IOTA learning group for foundations

Tags: python

is anybody interested in forming an online learning group for doing some basic examples in how to use IOTA with Python?
I am thinking of something along the lines:

- post data transaction to a recipient in the Tangle
- read the data transaction from the Tangle
- something around value transactions
- use MAM protocol
- use a wallet
- setup a Node
  ....

cheers
Norbert

Answer (score 1):

You can join one of the [X-Teams](https://wiki.iota.org/community/the-community/x-teams).

Btw, MAM is long deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I like this idea and as Ani pointed out it is possible to join or even champion an X-Team.

If you would like to push for this learning group, please get in touch with me.

Comment: I have just submitted an "IOTA Experience Team Application Form". Can you help me to get that going?

Comment: Hi! I saw your submission but cannot find you in the Discord.
Join us here https://discord.gg/iota

Comment: Hi Antonio, I joined  discord.gg/iota. I have to say, there is a lot of info on Discord and the wikis, but it is overwhelming. Using Python I am still unable to submit a simple transaction to the Tangle. Can we have a 30min call to clarify?

Comment: Hi! I pinged you on Discord, let us continue there